# Recurring a function splicing values into an array until condition met

Tags: javascript, arrays

This function finds a gap larger than a value, fills it with the average of the neighbouring values and returns the new array.

I need to recur this function until there is no more gaps greater than the gap value, in the example 5.

**How do I recur this function until there are no more gaps?**

```js
var chain = [0,2,6,44,70]
function fillgaps(chain,gap){
 var len = chain.length
 for(i=1;i<len;i++){
  var g = chain[i]-chain[i-1] 
   if(g>gap){
    var avrg = (chain[i]+chain[i-1])/2
    chain.splice(i,0,avrg)
    var len = 0
   }
 }
 return chain
}
var test = fillgaps(chain,5)
console.log(chain)
```

Comment: Did you post the question before you meant to? There is no question.

Comment: Bit confused by that answer but I'll reword it for you;

Comment: try using a loop

Comment: I tried, if you can show it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to call the whole function again. Instead place the index back a bit and let it continue from there, so it will reassess the new interval that was introduced:

```js
function fillgaps(chain,gap){
    var len = chain.length
    for(i=1;i<len;i++){
        var g = chain[i]-chain[i-1] 
        if(g>gap){
            var avrg = (chain[i]+chain[i-1])/2;
            chain.splice(i,0,avrg);
            len++;
            i--;
        }
    }
    return chain;
}
var chain = [0,2,6,44,70];
var test = fillgaps(chain,5)
console.log(test)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could reduce the array by using the last item of the result array and the actual item and use a function for checking the gap.

If a gap is found, the array is extended with the average and checked for a gap again.

```js
function fillgaps(chain, gap) {
    const
        iter = a => a.reduce((r, v) => r && r.concat(fill(r.pop(), v)) || [v], undefined),
        fill = (a, b) => gap + a < b ? iter([a, (a + b) / 2, b]) : [a, b];

    return iter(chain);
}

var chain = [0, 2, 6, 44, 70],
    result = fillgaps(chain, 5);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```